# How can I get rid of this prohibitory symbol continuosly blinking on the desktop of Ubuntu 20.04 until an audio file is played?

Tags: 20.04, sound, shortcut-keys

When my Ubuntu 20.04 system is booted this prohibitory symbol appears and blinks continuously until an audio file is started.

[image: stop sign on desktop]

Also, pausing the audio file works for only a few seconds; after that the file automatically continues to play.

Also, all my keyboard shortcuts for sound and media are disabled.

[image: shortcuts dialog - pause play and other options "disabled"]

The pause problem affects YouTube also.

Whenever an audio file is playing the prohibitory symbol is not there.

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: When the symbol is on the screen, are you able to type and use the keyboard? Or is the keyboard unresponsive?

Comment: the symbol is on the screen , the keyboard is responsive and i am able to type